# Create a Joomla Access Level to manage users in a particular Group

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator, acl, permissions, joomla-user-groups

My Joomla Version is 3.8
I want to create a Custom User Access Level to manage users in a particular group. I have a user group which is configured as the default user group when new registrations are done manually. At present user registrations are done by an administrator from background. 
I would like to create a user group/Access Level with rights to manage users of another group and with no other admin privileges. I mean create new, edit and Enable/Disable users of a particular group say Group A.

Is this possible in Joomla 3.8? If yes, how to go about this? If not, what's the alternate solution?

I explored and failed.

Answer (score 1):

Using the standard core functions it is not possible to to restrict the ability to manage users of a particular user group, in your example Group A. I would say that it might be possible with some custom code to limit the display of a particular group or check before saving that the user is allowed to be changed by the person/group.

To allow a group to have just the ability to administer Users requires you to set up a  user group as a sub group of the Manager group and then in each of the components you **do not** want them to have access to you need to change the permissions to Deny if they aren't already denied by inheritance.

A quick look through the JED doesn't show up any extensions that suggest they might be able to do what you want.